# connection pooling and lambda termination

Tags: node.js, connection-pooling, serverless-framework, serverless

I've been messing around with serverless and postgresql. It seems that connection pooling is possible, but when I declared a connection pool to my postgresql instance outside:

```
var pool = new pg.Pool(config);
```

Not calling `pool.end()` at the end of request handlers seem to cause `lambda-local` to not terminate when I call it.

If I call `pool.end()` lambda-local does terminate, but I wonder if this means that the function will stop working?

If I don't call pool.end(), will the function run forever on AWS, costing me a lot of money?

Answer (score 2):

This is because by default, the lambda callback waits for empty event loop before "freezing the process" [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-context.html#nodejs-prog-model-context-properties)

You can change this behavior by setting `context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop` to `false`. On subsequent calls, in case of "hot start", your lambda should be able to reuse the pool.

You can use [middy middleware](https://github.com/middyjs/middy/blob/4d63076abad12aa25ed6617106c7ec3286f51695/src/middlewares/warmup.js) or [serverless plugin](https://serverless.com/blog/keep-your-lambdas-warm/) to warmup your lambda and prevent cold start.

Also lambdas never run forever, the maximum execution duration per request is 300 seconds [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html#limits-list) and of course, you can set your own (lower) timeout.

That being said, it's a risky path and should be used with caution.